# Sublime Text Key Binding - app space between parentheses when press the space bar

Tags: key, sublimetext3, key-bindings

I added a key binding that puts the selector in-between parenthesis when I press "(" in SublimeText.

```
{ "keys": ["("], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "(${0:$SELECTION})"}, "context":
  [
    { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
    { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true }
  ]
},
```

However, I would like to create a key binding that turns (|) into ( | ) when I press the space bar and I am in-between the parenthesis.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this you want a key binding such as the following:

```json
{
    "keys": [" "],
    "command": "insert_snippet",
    "args": {
        "contents": " $0 "
    },
    "context": [
        // { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\($", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\)", "match_all": true }
    ],
}
```

The `insert_snippet` command inserts a snippet containing two space characters with the cursor centered between them, while the `context` entries make the binding active only when there is no selection, the text prior to the cursor ends in a `(` and the text following the cursor begins with a `)`.

As written this will always be active in this situation, but if desired you can also uncomment the first context entry here, which further restricts this binding to only be active when the `auto_match_enabled` setting is turned on. That would make it only active in cases where entering a single `(` character would auto-insert the pairing character.